# How to get additional information which is part of access token response from authorization server in OAuth2 client app

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

Access token response

```
{
    "access_token": "fd515395-ab03-4cc5-9ba4-03c42bdfdf189b73",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "refresh_token": "176ee948-ebdc-4d51-9768-08aa1dfdd081442",
    "expires_in": 10799,
    "scope": "user_info",
    "instance_url": "https://xxxx.xxx.com/xx-xxx-service"
}
```

I've tried as below but no luck

```
@RequestMapping("/securedPage")
    public String securedPage( Model model, OAuth2AuthenticationToken authToken ) {

        OAuth2AuthorizedClient client = clientService.loadAuthorizedClient( authToken.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId(), authToken.getName() );

        OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = client.getAccessToken();

        System.out.println( accessToken.getTokenValue() );
        System.out.println( accessToken.getExpiresAt() );
        System.out.println( client.getPrincipalName() );
        System.out.println( client.getRefreshToken().getTokenValue() );

        // Get "instance_url" here

        return "securedPage.html";
}
```

Comment: Is the first snippet contains access token response FROM an authentication server? Is the second snippet is a controller method of the Client? What's the class OAuth2AuthenticationToken and why it should be injected automatically to controller method? - Many questions, required more information. Usually on the Client the Principal object contains all information about request, response, client and user.

Comment: @DmitryIonash Is the first snippet contains access token response FROM an authentication server?
Ans: Yes

Comment: @DmitryIonash  Is the second snippet is a controller method of the Client? Ans: Yes

Comment: @DmitryIonash OAuth2AuthenticationToken and why it should be injected automatically to controller method? Ans: I need to send this information to my UI app which will send requests directly to resource server. The additional information is nothing but a resource server endpoint URL. I tried with Principal but not luck.

Answer (score 0):

I see 3 possible ways to get the result:

1. Using injecting `Principal` object. For Spring OAuth2 it's implemented with class `OAuth2Authentication`. You can find most of the information in this object - in `details`, `userAuthentication`, `storedRequest`. Inspect it and you will see what you need.
2. Get directly all required parameters with authentication request:

Service method:

```
var resourceDetails = ((OAuth2RestTemplate) restTemplate).getResource();
var headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
headers.setBasicAuth(resourceDetails.getClientId(), resourceDetails.getClientSecret());
var form = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
form.add("grant_type", "password");
form.add("username", "<username>");
form.add("password", "<password>");
var request = new HttpEntity<>(form, headers);
var response = restTemplate.postForObject(resourceDetails.getAccessTokenUri(), request, LinkedHashMap.class);
```

The object `response` contains all parameters like in your access token response.

One thing - you need to use a specific `restTemplate` like next:

```
var resourceDetails = new ClientCredentialsResourceDetails();
resourceDetails.setClientId("<clientId>");
resourceDetails.setClientSecret("<clientSecret>");
resourceDetails.setAccessTokenUri("<accessTokenUri>");
resourceDetails.setScope("<scopes>");
resourceDetails.setAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.header);
resourceDetails.setGrantType("client_credentials");
var restTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(resourceDetails, new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext());
var requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
requestFactory.setConnectTimeout(10000);
requestFactory.setConnectionRequestTimeout(10000);
requestFactory.setReadTimeout(10000);
restTemplate.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);
var tokenProvider = new ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider();
tokenProvider.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);
restTemplate.setAccessTokenProvider(new AccessTokenProviderChain(Arrays.<AccessTokenProvider>asList(
        new AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider(), new ImplicitAccessTokenProvider(),
        new ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider(), tokenProvider)));
```

3. Generate an object on the Authorization Server and to respond it with a similar restTemplate to the Client. This is an undesirable approach but it can be implemented also.